# Wrangler local development with Cloudflare Pages

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages, wrangler

I'm playing around with the new Cloudflare Functions functionality, specifically the file based routing. However I've found it tiresome to have to deploy and debug my functions in the cloud

I found this, which seems to say I can use Wrangler to connect to the Cloudfalre network and run functions locally:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/functions/#develop-and-preview-locally

But it keeps asking me for a root worker file: but there is no root file, its file based routing.

How do I get Cloudsflare Functions to work with wrangler local dev or miniflare?